# OpenCV error for accessing cv::Mat data

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

For any Mat type that I use with allowable types, I get an an error like below  when I try to do some assignment or write to stream etc. It happens on MSVC++ 2010 express compiler, it does not happen with gnu g++ compiler.

example flawed usage:

```
Mat M = Mat::zeros( image.size(),  DataType<int>::type  );

std::cout << M.at<int>( 0,0 ) << std::endl; // error

// OR

int x = M.at<int>( 0,0 ); // error
```

the two errors fired together:

on popup window

```
Unhandled exception at <some hex adress> in test.exe:Microsoft C++ exception: cv:xception at memory location <some hex adress>
```

and on console window

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ... \mat.hpp, line 537
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the matrix data type `CV_16U`.

The `.at` accessor functions are very meticulous, requiring very exact data types.  Some compilers ignore these issues, while others catch it early.

Rather than referencing the elements with `matrix.at<int>(row, col)`, `CV_16U` makes reference to the `unsigned short` data type.  Therefore, the elements can be accessed with `matrix.at<unsigned short>(row, col)`.

Comment: I did the following (already and once more now) but it doesnt work ... Mat M = Mat::zeros( image.size(),  CV_16S ); std::cout << M.at<int>( 0,0 ) << std::endl;

Comment: Right, but you're then calling things as int instead of short.  Depending on your compiler, they might resolve seamlessly and they might not.  Don't assume an implicit cast in your matrix references

Comment: Thanx. Explicit casting is the key point. I have not completely solved my problem though. What if I want to assign values from mat to mat. M1.at<float>(0,0) = M2.at<float>( i,j ) assuming they are both CV_32F or in the case when M2 is CV_32S

Comment: @Zoran What is the problem with that?  If the data types are equivalent, there should be no problems.  Is that giving you an error as well? (Did explicitly casting solve the original problem?)

Comment: explicit casting solved something like M.at<float>(0,0) = 0.0; while using CV_32F, but I cannot still assign values between the same type of matrices which is part of the original problem :( checking the 2.4.2 documentation as of now

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem... What is your allocation error? Your problem might be that one of your matrices isn't actually initialized

Comment: Both are actually initialized. This is the problematic line: M1.at<float>(0,0) = (float)M2.at<int>( i,j ); where M1 is CV_32F anf M2 is CV_32S. When I run this I get the error in the question. CV_32S is obtained by convolving with several kernels of type uchar etc., so I suspect there is a casting problem with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20050/discussion-between-chris-and-zoran)

Comment: Solved by "very" explicit type conversions ! My experience: Dont think OpenCV will handle even the slightest thing for you and look at functions like convertTo, convertScaleAbs, ... be careful with type casting i.e. e.g. 16U is unsigned short, not something else. Lastly, be careful w. gnu c++ compiler, it may not throw type conversion errors. Thanks to Chris.

Comment: @Zoran Thanks for the update.  It is very meticulous and sometimes compiler dependent.  Glad I could help

Comment: Please don't mark answer accepted if it contains no helpful information. Someone should update the answer to add correct solution or post another answer with the solution.

Comment: @Riateche Indeed, I was in the process of updating it when you wrote that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe openCV has an int data type image.
The integer type is generally CV_16s, ie 16bit short, so use

Comment: it does in v.2.4.x that I know of, but casting should be properly handled.